# Evaluate $2i\int_{-1}^1\frac{\operatorname{Li}_2(-ix^2)-\operatorname{Li}_2(ix^2)}{x^2}dx$, where $\operatorname{Li}_2(s)$ is the polylogarithm

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Let $\sqrt{-1}=i$ the imaginary unit.

Playing with Wolfram Alpha online calculator I know that $$I:=\int_{-1}^1\left(\int_{-1}^1\left(\int_{-1}^1\frac{1}{1-ix^2yz}dy\right)dz\right)dx=\int_{-1}^1\left(\int_{-1}^1\frac{2\arctan(x^2z)}{x^2z}dz\right)dx,\tag{1}$$
and this RHS equals to $$\int_{-1}^1\frac{2i(\operatorname{Li}_2(-ix^2)-\operatorname{Li}_2(ix^2))}{x^2}dx\tag{2}$$ where $\operatorname{Li}_2(s)$ is the polylogarithm (see if you need the definition from this [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Polylogarithm.html)).

> **Question.** I would like to get, if it is possible a closed-form for $I$, thus I need to evaluate 
>   $$\int_{-1}^1\frac{2i(\operatorname{Li}_2(-ix^2)-\operatorname{Li}_2(ix^2))}{x^2}dx.$$
>   Can you finish this task providing a simplified form of the result? **Many thanks.**

As summary, as I've said using [Wolfram Alpha online calculator](https://www.wolframalpha.com) I've calculated the definite integrals

`int 1/(1-i x^2 y z)dy, from y=-1 to 1`

and

`int (2 tan^(-1)(x^2 z))/(x^2 z)dz, from z=-1 to 1`

Also we know the indefinite integral

`int  (2 i (Polylog[2,-i x^2] - Polylog[2,i x^2]))/x^2 dx`

I believe also that

$$2i(\frac{-\operatorname{Li}_2(-ix^2)+\operatorname{Li}_2(ix^2)}{x} \Big|_{-1}^1=-8C,$$ where $C$ is the Catalan's constant, and $$(\frac{2i}{x}2(-\log(1-ix^2)+\log(1+ix^2))\Big|_{-1}^1=-4\pi.$$

Feel free to add a different approach than previous to evaluate $I$, or our integral in $(2)$.

Comment: If some user is interested, to think this variation I was inspired in a slide related to an integral due to Córdoba, see page 39/41, from this talk by professor Chamizo [from his homepage on the Universidad Autónoma de Madrid](https://www.uam.es/personal_pdi/ciencias/fchamizo/talks/antonio/antonio.pdf)

Comment: [W & $\large\alpha$ yields](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2+I+Integrate%5B(PolyLog%5B2,+-I+x%5E2%5D+-+PolyLog%5B2,+I+x%5E2%5D)%2Fx%5E2,+%7Bx,+-1,+++++1%7D%5D) $\approx 7.8490$.

Comment: Many thanks @FelixMarin

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**. By integrating
$$
\frac{2i(\operatorname{Li}_2(-ix^2)-\operatorname{Li}_2(ix^2))}{x^2}
$$ *termwise*, which is allowed here, one gets
$$
\int_{-1}^1\frac{2i(\operatorname{Li}_2(-ix^2)-\operatorname{Li}_2(ix^2))}{x^2}dx=4i\cdot\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{i^n\left((-1)^n-1\right)}{(2n-1)n^2}
$$ by using a partial fraction decomposition, the preceding series admits a closed form, one gets
$$
\int_{-1}^1\frac{2i(\operatorname{Li}_2(-ix^2)-\operatorname{Li}_2(ix^2))}{x^2}dx=4\pi\sqrt{2}+4\sqrt{2}\ln\left(3+2\sqrt{2}\right)-4\pi-8 C
$$ where $C$ is the [Catalan constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_constant).

Comment: Many thaks for your answer. I am going to study it this afternoon.

Comment: @user243301 You are very welcome.

Comment: +1. It's nice because Jonqui$\mathrm{\grave{e}}$re Inversion Formula just yields the $\Re$ part for $\mathrm{Li}_{2}$ and we are in need of $\Im$.

Answer (score 0):

There is an additional approximate solution for this integral.

For $-1<x<1$ the  expression $i(Li_2(-ix^2) - Li_2(ix^2))$ can be approximated with $2x^2$.

As a consequence, we can write $\int_{-1}^1\frac{2 (2x^2)}{x^2}dx=\int_{-1}^14dx=8$. This comes out with the cost of an inaccuracy, that is this approximation calculates a number of 8 instead of 7.84904 which is calculated using numerical integration with mathematica.

Comment: Many thanks for your contribution.

Answer (score 0):

In the same spirit as Dimitris U., let us consider the Taylor series built around $x=0$.

You will have $$\frac{2 i \left(\text{Li}_2\left(-i x^2\right)-\text{Li}_2\left(i
   x^2\right)\right)}{x^2}=4 \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k \frac{x^{4k}}{(2k+1)^2}$$ leading to $$\int_{-1}^1\frac{2 i \left(\text{Li}_2\left(-i x^2\right)-\text{Li}_2\left(i
   x^2\right)\right)}{x^2}\,dx=8 \sum_{k=0}^\infty  \frac{ (-1)^k}{(2 k+1)^2\, (4 k+1)}$$ and, as Olivier Oloa answered, take into account the fact that $$\frac{1}{(2 k+1)^2 (4 k+1)}=\frac{4}{4 k+1}-\frac{2}{2 k+1}-\frac{1}{(2 k+1)^2}$$ Using the summation, it would required many terms even for a moderate accuracy.

Comment: Many thnaks one more time.